# Confirming Password Using Angular Custom Validators

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-custom-validators

I've got a password field as well as a confirm password field and everything works fine if you're filling out the form from top to bottom. However, if I put in the password / password confirmation and then go back to change the password field, the confirmation field stays 'valid' unless I change it again to trigger the custom validator to "check if passwords match" again.

**form.component.ts** - the form gets it's "layout" so-to-speak from register.component.ts. This is so I can dynamically build forms.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input                } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router                                  } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService                              } from 'src/app/services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector:  'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  // Variable Declarations
  @Input() form: {
    api: string
    title: string,
    inputs: [{ placeholder: string, type: string, name: string, validators: []}],
    link: { text: string, url: string },
    button: string
   };
   formGroup: FormGroup;

  // Variable Initialization
   inputControls = {};
   message = {};

  // Constructor
  constructor(private api: ApiService, private router: Router) { }

  // On Component Init
  ngOnInit() {

    // Build form
    this.form.inputs.forEach(input => {
      if (input.name === 'confirm') {
        this.inputControls[input.name] = new FormControl(null, [this.PasswordsMatch]);
      } else {
        this.inputControls[input.name] = new FormControl(null, input.validators);
      }
    });

    this.formGroup = new FormGroup(this.inputControls);
  }

  PasswordsMatch = (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} | null => {
    // Check if root exists first - otherwise console error ".value of undefined"
    if (control.root.get('password')) {
      return control.value === control.root.get('password').value ? null : {mismatch: true};
   }
  }
}
```

**form.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="formGroup">

    <span>{{ form.title }}</span>

    <div *ngFor = "let input of form.inputs; let i = index">
      <input [type]            = "input.type"
             [placeholder]     = "input.placeholder"
             [formControlName] = "input.name">
    </div>

    <button [disabled]="!formGroup.valid">{{ form.button }}</button>
    <a [routerLink]="form.link.url">{{ form.link.text }}</a>

  </form>
</div>
```

**register.component.ts** - I couldn't figure out how to pass the custom validator for the confirm password field, so I just passed Validators.required but this simply gets overwritten with a custom validator when the form is built.

```
import { Component  } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent {

  // Validators (Validators.required is used to differentiate between error messages)
  validators = {
    name:     [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z]{2,20}') ],
    email:    [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}')],
    username: [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9.+%+-]{1,30}')],
    password: [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*-_=+]{10,}')],
    confirm:  [ Validators.required, ]
  };

  // Form data
  form = {
    api: 'register',
    title: 'Are you ready?',
    inputs: [
      { placeholder: 'First Name',       type: 'text',     name: 'name',     validators: this.validators.name     },
      { placeholder: 'Email Address',    type: 'email',    name: 'email',    validators: this.validators.email    },
      { placeholder: 'Mage Name',        type: 'text',     name: 'username', validators: this.validators.username },
      { placeholder: 'Password',         type: 'password', name: 'password', validators: this.validators.password },
      { placeholder: 'Confirm Password', type: 'password', name: 'confirm',  validators: this.validators.confirm  },
    ],
    link: { text: 'I\'m already a Wizard!', url: '/login' },
    button: 'I\'m Ready for War'
  };

  constructor() {}
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you should add validation to formgroup not to the field.
An example:

```
this.userform = this.fb.group({
            email: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.email ]),
            passwordGroup: new FormGroup(                  {
                    password: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required,                        Validators.minLength(6) ]),
                    passwordConfirm: new FormControl('')
                },
                PasswordValidation.MatchPassword
            )
        });

export class PasswordValidation {
    static MatchPassword(AC: AbstractControl) {
        const password = AC.get('password').value; // to get value in input tag
        const confirmPassword = AC.get('passwordConfirm').value; // to get value in input tag
        if (password !== confirmPassword) {
            AC.get('passwordConfirm').setErrors({ MatchPassword: true });
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tano. I'm not using the FormBuilder class since I wasn't able to figure out how to dynamically build the form if I used it. I don't quite understand why shouldn't have validators on the fields themselves rather than the formgroup. Reading the documentation it looks like the validators are placed on the form controls and those form controls are added to a formgroup. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: If you want to validate a single control, you have to add to that control, if you want to validate more controls, you have to add the validator to the group or add the same validator to every single control which is related to the validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add a possible solution / workaround for anyone trying to build forms a similar way.

I updated my **form.component.html** to call a function on (keyup).

```
<div class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="formGroup">

    <span>{{ form.title }}</span>

    <div *ngFor = "let input of form.inputs; let i = index">
      <input [type]            = "input.type"
             [placeholder]     = "input.placeholder"
             [formControlName] = "input.name"
             (keyup)           = "checkPasswordsMatch(input.name)">
    </div>

    <button [disabled]="!formGroup.valid">{{ form.button }}</button>
    <a [routerLink]="form.link.url">{{ form.link.text }}</a>

  </form>
</div>
```

In my **form.component.ts** I added a simple checkPasswordsMatch function that manually sets the errors for the confirm password field when the password field is changed if they no longer match. See last function below:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input                } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router                                  } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService                              } from 'src/app/services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector:  'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  // Variable Declarations
  @Input() form: {
    api: string
    title: string,
    inputs: [{ placeholder: string, type: string, name: string, validators: []}],
    link: { text: string, url: string },
    button: string
   };
   formGroup: FormGroup;

  // Variable Initialization
   inputControls = {};
   message = {};

  // Constructor
  constructor(private api: ApiService, private router: Router) { }

  // On Component Init
  ngOnInit() {

    // Build form
    this.form.inputs.forEach(input => {
      if (input.name === 'confirm') {
        this.inputControls[input.name] = new FormControl(null, [this.PasswordsMatch]);
      } else {
        this.inputControls[input.name] = new FormControl(null, input.validators);
      }
    });

    this.formGroup = new FormGroup(this.inputControls);
  }

  // Check if confirm === password anytime the confirm field changes
  PasswordsMatch = (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} | null => {

    // Check if root exists first - otherwise console error ".value of undefined"
    if (control.root.get('password')) {
      return control.value === control.root.get('password').value ? null : {mismatch: true};
   }
  }

  // Check if confirm === password anytime the password field changes
  // "input" is the name of the input field triggering this function
  checkPasswordsMatch(input) {
    if (input === 'password') {
      const p = this.formGroup.get('password');
      const c = this.formGroup.get('confirm');

      c.value === p.value ? c.setErrors(null) : c.setErrors({mismatch: true});
    }
  }
}
```

Since all of these inputs are part of the same FormGroup, the form is only valid when all inputs are valid. Changing the password after the password confirm field has been validated will cause the `checkPasswordsMatch()` to run and set the errors manually for the confirm field if they don't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution you need ng2-validation library for this

```
import { CustomValidators } from 'ng2-validation';
const password = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}$')]);
const confirmPassword = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, CustomValidators.equalTo(password)]);
this.form = this.fb.group({
      password: password,
      confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
    });
```